# JS function calls won't work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I tried writing a simple JS canvas but it wouldn't draw. If I call the renderCanvas() from the Dev Console in chrome it works, but not if I call it in code. Any ideas why? I'm sure that the picture is there...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSolitaire</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <script>
    renderCanvas(); 
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
    var bgReady = false;
    var bgImage = new Image();
    bgImage.src = "background.png";
    bgImage.onload = new function(){
        bgReady = true;
    };  

    function renderCanvas(){
        if(bgReady)
            ctx.drawImage(0, 0, bgImage);
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the `new` keyword before `function`?

Comment: You have renderCanvs as the first call and you have not even started loading the background. Try putting renderCanvas in the onload function, as you have to wait for the image to load anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point of using bgReady you can just do this

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.src = "background.png";
bgImage.onload = function() {
    renderCanvas(); 
};  
function renderCanvas() {
    ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
};
```

Comment: This works, but I had to add the bgImage as the 1st paramater to drawImage:  ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);

Comment: yea just checked the function it should be ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy); thank you sir.

Comment: @WinterCore. Wow, and you told us that it worked from console? How can that be?